# Revert usage of Fn key to control notebook (e.g. brightness, sound)

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

after upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04 on my Dell XPS 13 (2015) I noticed that the function keys are now "inverted". Before the update I had to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> **and** the corresponding <kbd>F</kbd> key at the top to change the brightness, sound volume etc.

Now, I don't have to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key anymore. Instead, reloading a website (earlier only with <kbd>F5</kbd>) now requires  the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

How can I revert this behavior and switch back to the old shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same laptop. You have two options:

1. Change that behavior in BIOS, there is a option
2. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (On <kbd>Esc</kbd> is a mark FN)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Many thanks. The second approach did the trick.